# How to configure SmtpAppender in log4j2.xml in java?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, smtpappender

I am trying to use SmtpAppender in my java application but its giving below error when I start my application.

**'ERROR could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender for element SMTP: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource'**

**I am using log4j-api-2.17.0.jar, log4j-core-2.17.0.jar, javax.mail-1.5.6.jar.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" strict="true" name="MyApp">
  <Appenders>
    <SMTP name="Mail" subject="Error Log" to="test@test.com" from="test1@test.com"
          smtpHost="test.email.com" bufferSize="50">

<PatternLayout>
  <pattern>%d {yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS } [%t] %c{1} %msg%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>

    </SMTP>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Mail"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You need jakarta.activation.xxxx.jar in your classpath